# Cannot Upload image to server using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to upload image to the server, The below code is working properly when i run the the code locally on my system, but when i upload it to the server it gives error message - The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Login.Models.User', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable'[Login.Models.User]'.Please help to solve this issue.

```
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file,  Login.Models.User model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            var user=db.User.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Userid==model.Userid);

            if (file != null)
            {
            string pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/profile/"), pic);
            file.SaveAs(path);
            user.imagepath = "http://sampleApp.com/images/profile/" + pic;
            }

        Catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("",ex.Message);
        }
        return View("ViewAdmin",model);
    }
    db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(user,System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("User");
}
```

View

```
@model Login.Models.User

@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{  
    <label for="file">Upload Image:</label> 
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" /> 
}
```

Comment: change tbl_Image model to Login.Models.User

Comment: It was by mistake i have written tbl_Image, but after changing the same message, but it is perfectly running on local system.

Comment: Could you edit your question and put the upload section in view.cshtml

Comment: I have added Code snippet of View.cshtml.

Comment: It is not encapsulated by another form right? Have you tried deleting all the contents from remote server and upload it again? There may be some caching issues over bin file or something else.

Comment: Yes.. i have checked locally and then uploaded it on server but the same issue..

Comment: I think there is something else overridding your model. What happens when you change your method signature to public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file,  List<Login.Models.User> model)

Comment: shouldn't the `return View("ViewAdmin",model);` be inside the catch block? otherwise you only run the `db.SaveChanges();` when the modelstate is invalid

Comment: Give read/write permission to file uploaded folder i.e images..